# Store the created KeyPairs in the node

Tags: solana

I work in a crypto exchange company and I would like to keep all the accounts created in my node. We need to keep the private keys, public keys etc. of the accounts. While creating the wallet there is no IP address of the node is passed so I could not clearly understood how it's work. I'd like to create a wallet with web3.js and store it in the node.

```
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const { binary_to_base58 } = require("base58-js");

let decodedPublicKey;
let decodedPrivateKey;
let connection = new web3.Connection(web3.clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
let publicKey;
let privateKey;

const createWallet = async () => {
  // Generate a new random public key
  var from = web3.Keypair.generate();

  publicKey = from._keypair.publicKey;
  privateKey = from._keypair.secretKey;

  decodedPublicKey = binary_to_base58(publicKey);
  decodedPrivateKey = binary_to_base58(privateKey);

  console.log("Public Key: " + decodedPublicKey);
  console.log("Private Key: " + decodedPrivateKey);

  //   console.log(publicKey);
  //   console.log(privateKey);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new keypair with `web3.Keypair.generate()`, it's entirely offline, without any intervention from the node.  If you want to store these keypairs, you can save them to a file / database / keystore from the raw bytes of the keypair, ie:

```
fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('keypair.txt', from.secretKey);
```

And then later to load it up:

```
const secretKeyData = fs.readFileSync('keypair.txt');
const from = Keypair.fromSecretKey(secretKeyData);
```

Note that this is untested pseudocode, so there might be some wrong bits in the encoding.